# How to remove " from a string in c# in unity

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple program in Unity or C# I guess, that takes a python list( ["4", "2", "6", "9"] ) in form of a string and converts it to c# list
This is my code:

```
public List<string> ListMaker(string input)
    {
        input = input.Trim(new char[] {'['});
        input = input.Trim(new char[] {']'});
        input = input.Trim(new char[] {"""});
        List<string> Output = input.Split(',').ToList();
        return Output;
    }
```

, and I am having trouble getting rid of the " symbol
since when I use input.Trim(new char[] {'"'}); it doesn't work like with the [] symbols ( input.Trim(new char[] {']'}); ) so I used the " equivalent (input = input.Trim(new char[] {"""});) and the Console says that it can not convert type string to char. Does anyone have a solution to this problem or am I missing something that is already Online?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should start by picking a language.

Comment: Side note: I'm pretty sure you are trying to https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+parse+json+unity3d

Answer (score 0):

If the string of your Python List looks as follows
`["1","2","3","4"]` I would reccomend to use the Replace function because trim does only remove trailing and leading characters. Therefore your code may look like:

```cs
public List<string> ListMaker(string input) {
    input = input.Trim(new char[] { '[', ']' }).Replace("\"", "");
    return input.Split(',').ToList();
}
```

If you have spaces between your commas you may replace them too.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [Escape Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-170)

```
public List<string> ListMaker(string input)
{
    input = input.Trim(new char[] {'['});
    input = input.Trim(new char[] {']'});
    input = input.Trim(new char[] {'\"'});
    List<string> Output = input.Split(',').ToList();
    return Output;
}
```

shorter Version would be:

```
public List<string> ListMaker(string input)
{
    input = input.Trim(new char[] { '[', ']', '\"' });
    List<string> Output = input.Split(',').ToList();
    return Output;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the support, but if I do that I get the Error Message: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char'

Comment: did you see the \" ? this should work. I tried it on my side and it works fine =)

Comment: thats weird I inserted exactly your code and it didn't work is there some differance between c# versions, it gave me the error above.

Comment: The escape sequence is useless here, since it's a char array with single quotes.

Comment: Suggesting to pars JSON with string manipulation... not really sure this is the best way.

Comment: why is it useless?

When I call this method ListMaker("\"Hello World") I get back "Hello World". That is the result I want, isn't it?

Comment: Did you try your code on OP input?

Comment: @MartinBartolomé doublequotes inside single quotes are always escaped and do not need a \ before.